# How to render Chart.js 2.x tooltips on top of everything

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I'm using **Chart.js 2.6.0** and I have been working on an example to render custom graphics. You can see a live demo at: https://jsfiddle.net/arminzia/bm4ezdur/.

Basically I'm rendering circles on top of each bar to denote the value. here's the code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    data: {
        labels: ["2 Jan", "9 Jan", "16 Jan", "23 Jan", "30 Jan", "6 Feb", "13 Feb"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [16, 87, 56, 35, 88, 60, 12],
            backgroundColor: "#4082c4"
        }]
    },
    options: {
            "hover": {
            "animationDuration": 0
        },
        "animation": {
            "duration": 1,
                        "onComplete": function () {
                            var chartInstance = this.chart,
                                ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

                            ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                            ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                            this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                                var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                                meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                                    var data = dataset.data[index] + '$';                            

                  var centerX = bar._model.x;
                  var centerY = bar._model.y - 10;
                  var radius = 22;

                  ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                  ctx.fill();
                  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
                  ctx.strokeStyle = '#4082c4';
                  ctx.stroke();

                  ctx.fillStyle = '#4082c4';
                  ctx.font = "bold 14px Calibri";
                  ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y);
                                });
                            });
                        }
        },
            legend: {
            "display": false
        },
        tooltips: {
            "enabled": true
         },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    gridLines: {
                    display : true
                },
                ticks: {
                        display: true,
                    beginAtZero:true,
                    max: 140
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                    barThickness: 40,
                    gridLines: {
                    display : false
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Now the problem is, tooltips are being hidden under these circles. I've been struggling with this for too long and haven't found any solution or anything useful from the docs.

How can I force tooltips to be rendered on top of these circles? On top of everything actually, something like *z-index: 1000*.

Comment: The problem seems to be that when tooltips are enabled, every time you hover over the canvas, the animation function is triggered again. I tested this by adding an alert to the animation `onComplete`. With  `tooltips: { enabled : true }`, the alert was triggered on every hover. When I changed it to `tooltips: false`, the alert was only triggered once.

Comment: @TotZam correct. but if i disable tooltips then nothing is shown. I need to display tooltips on click/touch events, hover is not necessary. But again, they should be rendered on top of my canvas renderings.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to update this post. The answer is to use External (Custom) Tooltips. That's basically rendering HTML elements to create tooltips. Read more on the docs [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips).